# TCP Socket Round Trip Time faster than Network Stack Latency?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

I have a experimental setup with two machines, each in the same network (they can ping one another), and they are both connected directly with an ethernet cable, each having a 10Gbps network card (IXGBE driver).

I have used this [code](https://vilimpoc.org/research/ku-latency/), which uses to measure the latency in the Linux network stack between kernel and user space. Using this, I got ~100 microseconds latency. However, after writing a simple Server/Client using sockets in C, I found that the round trip latency between the two hosts (when using a directly connected ethernet) was actually less than the latency of the kernel stack, which I don't get.

Below is the code for my Server/Client. The server simply listens for a TCP client, and responds with the message send with the client after reading it. The client simply connects to the server, and sends a message.

Here is my code for the server.c

```c
#define PORT            8080
#define BUFFER_SIZE     1024
#define PACKET_SIZE     1024

int main() {
    int     socket_fd, new_socket, rc;

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_fd  == 0) {
        perror("Socket creation error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    // Set socket options with setsockopt
    int opt = 1;
    rc = setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt));
    if (rc < 0) {
        perror("Setsockopt failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Bind socket to address:port
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    rc = bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));
    if (rc < 0) {
        perror("Socket bind failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Listening to %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr), ntohs(address.sin_port));
    if (listen(socket_fd, 3)) {
        perror("Listen failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Accept
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    new_socket = accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen);
    if (new_socket < 0) {
        perror("Accept failure");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Address of connected client
    char ip_address[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(address.sin_addr), ip_address, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    printf("New connection from %s:%d\n", ip_address, ntohs(address.sin_port));
    
    // Listen and respond
    int val_read, val_send;
    char    buff[BUFFER_SIZE];
    while (1) {
        memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
        val_read = read(new_socket, buff, sizeof(buff));
        if(val_read == -1) {
            perror("Read failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (val_read > 0) {
            val_send = send(new_socket, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
            if (val_send == -1) {
                perror("Send failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
    close(socket_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my code for the client.c

```c
#define PORT            8080
#define NUM_MESSAGES    1024
#define ROLLING_COUNT   32
#define PACKET_SIZE     32
#define BUFFER_SIZE     1024
#define DEST_ADDRESS    "192.168.10.223"

int main() {
    int sock = 0;
    int total_latency = 0;

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct in_addr dest_addr; 
    memset(&dest_addr, 0, sizeof(struct in_addr));
    inet_pton(AF_INET, DEST_ADDRESS, &dest_addr);


    serv_addr.sin_addr = dest_addr;
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);


    // Print out the options to use
    printf("Destination address is %s\n",       inet_ntoa(dest_addr));
    printf("Destination port    is %d\n",       PORT);
    
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("Socket creation error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Connect
    int c = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    if (c < 0) {
        perror("Connection failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Connectioned to server!\n");


    // Connection and out times
    struct timeval start_time, end_time;
    char message[PACKET_SIZE] = {};
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {};

    memset(message, 'A', strlen(message));
    double latency;

    // Send and recv
    printf("Ready to send/recv messages\n");\

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_MESSAGES; i++) {
        gettimeofday(&start_time, NULL);

        if (send(sock, message, sizeof(message), 0) == -1) {
            perror("Send failed");
            continue;
        }

        if (recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), SO_RCVTIMEO) == -1) {
            perror("Recv failed");
            continue;
        }

        gettimeofday(&end_time, NULL);
        latency     =   (end_time.tv_sec - start_time.tv_sec) * 1000000 + 
                        (end_time.tv_usec - start_time.tv_usec);
        printf("%d Message sent at %d.%06d, recv at %d.%06d, latency %06d\n", 
            i, start_time.tv_sec, start_time.tv_usec, end_time.tv_sec, end_time.tv_usec, latency);
    }
    printf("Finished!");
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}#define PORT            8080
#define NUM_MESSAGES    1024
#define ROLLING_COUNT   32
#define PACKET_SIZE     32
#define BUFFER_SIZE     1024
#define DEST_ADDRESS    "<target_ipv4_address>"

int main() {
    int sock = 0;
    int total_latency = 0;

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct in_addr dest_addr; 
    memset(&dest_addr, 0, sizeof(struct in_addr));
    inet_pton(AF_INET, DEST_ADDRESS, &dest_addr);


    serv_addr.sin_addr = dest_addr;
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);


    // Print out the options to use
    printf("Destination address is %s\n",       inet_ntoa(dest_addr));
    printf("Destination port    is %d\n",       PORT);
    
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("Socket creation error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Connect
    int c = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    if (c < 0) {
        perror("Connection failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Connectioned to server!\n");


    // Connection and out times
    struct timeval start_time, end_time;
    char message[PACKET_SIZE] = {};
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {};

    memset(message, 'A', strlen(message));
    double latency;

    // Send and recv
    printf("Ready to send/recv messages\n");\

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_MESSAGES; i++) {
        gettimeofday(&start_time, NULL);

        if (send(sock, message, sizeof(message), 0) == -1) {
            perror("Send failed");
            continue;
        }

        if (recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), SO_RCVTIMEO) == -1) {
            perror("Recv failed");
            continue;
        }

        gettimeofday(&end_time, NULL);
        latency     =   (end_time.tv_sec - start_time.tv_sec) * 1000000 + 
                        (end_time.tv_usec - start_time.tv_usec);
        printf("%d Message sent at %d.%06d, recv at %d.%06d, latency %06d\n", 
            i, start_time.tv_sec, start_time.tv_usec, end_time.tv_sec, end_time.tv_usec, latency);
    }
    printf("Finished!");
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

The latency should be the time difference when the client sends a message and after it is received.

This is where I am confused. Running the two programs, I get a reasonable round trip time using the normal eth0 interface, the network interface connected to a shared network. However when I use the interface that connects the two machines directly by ethernet cable, I get unreasonably low round trip time. For example, the round trip time of the eth0 interface is about 900-1000 microseconds, while the latter is less than ~80 microseconds.

Is there something I am missing here, how can the round trip time be so low?

PS. At the same time, I used ping after the client/server was setup, and ping times were much lower after the server code was running, why is this? After the server code was closed, ping times returned to normal

Comment: Interesting. Maybe the routing table lookup also takes some time and is being cached for a while?

Comment: @Rob I agree that it might do so for perhaps the first few pings, but the time difference is pretty drastic. Pinging eth0 on the second machine from the first gives about ~.9ms, but after a tcp connection is completed/initiated, I get about a ~.5ms round trip time after pinging again.

Comment: Are there some offloading capabilities activated or configured? Means, could it be that some packet handling is already done in network hardware and outside of CPU and kernel? The network card and driver itself seems to support such.

Comment: @U880D Would a base CentOS operating system have that configured? Or is this not an OS related problem at all?

Comment: The "hidden" parts of the connection are the network stack of the OS and the driver. Hard to say...

Comment: "_Would a base CentOS operating system have that configured?_", it will depend on the kernel and if it was compiled with such features. In general RHEL is supporting some features since v6, and so CentOS.

Comment: Is your setup running on bare-metal? What kind of hardware is it? Which CentOS version with which kernel you are using and which driver version? If there is a virtualization or other abstraction layer, which one? Can you describe your installed stack in more detail?

Comment: I am running CentOS 7, bare metal, with linux kernel version 3.10.0-1160.88.1.el7.x86_64.

Comment: Maybe you can start with [Disable TCP Offloading completely generically and easily](https://serverfault.com/questions/421995/) or [How to persist `ethtool` settings through reboot](https://serverfault.com/questions/463111/) to exclude that as reason.

Comment: You don't seem to be setting TCP_NODELAY